# SQL Insert With Unique Constraint using Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, insert, sql-server-2008-r2, unique-constraint

This is a generic question with a specific example.

I have a table with three fields (genreID (PK IDENTITY), genre, and subGenre).  The table has a unique constraint on (genre, subGenre) combination.

I am wondering how I could go about modifying the stored procedure to insert if it DOES NOT exist in the table, otherwise return the genreID of the existing genre if it DOES exist.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertGenre
    @genreID int OUTPUT,
    @genre varchar(100),
    @subGenre varchar(100)= NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Genre
    (
        genre,
        subGenre
    )
    Values (
        @genre,
        @subGenre
    )

    SELECT @genreID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to select the row that would be inserted by your SP before you do the insert:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertGenre
    @genreID int OUTPUT,
    @genre varchar(100),
    @subGenre varchar(100)= NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- if the row to be inserted already exists, put the genreID into the @genreID output parameter 
    SELECT @genreID = genreID
    FROM Genre 
    WHERE genre = @genre 
    AND subGenre = @subGenre

    IF @genreID IS NULL -- if the genreID was not found, do an insert and select the new genreID to the @genreID output parameter
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Genre
        (
            genre,
            subGenre
        )
        Values (
            @genre,
            @subGenre
        )

        SELECT @genreID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: +1, but also, be sure to put the select and insert inside a single transaction by wrapping it in BEGIN TRANSACTION and COMMIT TRANSACTION.  Otherwise, duplicate records are possible if the stored procedure is executed multiple times at the same time.

Comment: I tested - it works...  im curious though, the time to insert ~5,000 records was 16 seconds without the SELECT statement in there, and still 16 seconds with the SELECT statement --- im just wondering why there is no loss of speed here (granted im inserting 5k records in a table starting with 0 records, and there are no duplicates being attempted to insert)